# Correct way to quit a Qt program?

Tags: qt, resources, exit, quit

How should I quit a Qt Program, e.g when loading a data file, and discovered file corruption, and user need to quit this app or re-initiate data file?

Should I:

1. call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`
2. call `QApplication::quit()`
3. call `QCoreApplication::quit()`

And difference between (2) and (3)?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

QApplication is derived from QCoreApplication and thereby inherits `quit()` which is a public slot of `QCoreApplication`, so there is no difference between `QApplication::quit()` and `QCoreApplication::quit()`.

As we can read in the documentation of [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) it *"tells the application to exit with return code 0 (success)."*. If you want to exit because you discovered file corruption then you may not want to exit with return code zero which means success, so you should call [`QCoreApplication::exit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit) because you can provide a non-zero returnCode which, by convention, indicates an error.

It is important to note that *"if the event loop is not running, this function (QCoreApplication::exit()) does nothing"*, so in that case you should call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

Answer (score 33):

You can call `qApp->exit();`. I always use that and never had a problem with it.

If you application is a command line application, you might indeed want to return an exit code. It's completely up to you what the code is.

Answer (score 2):

While searching this very question I discovered this example in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit).

```
QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit");
connect(quitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Mutatis mutandis for your particular action of course.

Along with this note.

> It's good practice to always connect signals to this slot using a
> QueuedConnection. If a signal connected (non-queued) to this slot is
> emitted before control enters the main event loop (such as before "int
> main" calls exec()), the slot has no effect and the application never
> exits. Using a queued connection ensures that the slot will not be
> invoked until after control enters the main event loop.
>
> It's common to connect the QGuiApplication::lastWindowClosed() signal
> to quit()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt Jambi, this should work:

```
QApplication.closeAllWindows();
```

Comment: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

Answer (score -1):

if you need to close your application from main() you can use this code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication app(argc, argv);
...
if(!QSslSocket::supportsSsl()) return app.exit(0);
...
return app.exec();
}
```

The program will terminated if OpenSSL is not installed

Comment: I think this does not compile. app.exit(0) does not return an int. Use `if(!QSslSocket::supportsSsl()) {return 0;};`. Because app.exec() has not been called at this line, app.exit(0) does nothing, see documentation of QCoreApplication::exit(): _If the event loop is not running, this function does nothing._

Answer (score -10):

```
//How to Run App

bool ok = QProcess::startDetached("C:\\TTEC\\CozxyLogger\\CozxyLogger.exe");
qDebug() <<  "Run = " << ok;


//How to Kill App

system("taskkill /im CozxyLogger.exe /f");
qDebug() << "Close";
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Tfx.png)

Comment: the question is not about detaching new processes

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it